API changes when using app_store_scraper in Python?
Last summer, I created code for scraping Apple podcast reviews based on the official documentation provided for app-store-scraper:
https://pypi.org/project/app-store-scraper/
Here is the relevant section from my longer Jupyter notebook:
# import packages

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

from app_store_scraper import AppStore

# app_name = podcast name from URL
# app_id = podcast id from URL

podcast = AppStore(country='us', app_name='black-girl-gone-a-true-crime-podcast', app_id = '1556267741') 

podcast.review(how_many=7000) # change number if necessary

reviews=podcast.reviews

print("This podcast has ", len(reviews), "reviews.")

df = pd.DataFrame()

# columns in each review = date, review, rating, isEdited, userName, title

podcastdf = pd.DataFrame(np.array(podcast.reviews),columns=['review'])

display(podcastdf)

Unfortunately, I now get a 401 error when running the code again and I wonder if there are any changes in the Apple API that prevent me from collecting the data.
Or maybe there's some kind of dependency issue because packages have been updated.

Well, 401 means unauthorised so i guess they blocked something

I know what the error means but was wondering if other users had more details, also on what to, e.g. getting an API key or so. At the moment, API access is all part of the package I am using, so I am not entering a personal key.

PS: I see that someone released a new package for the same purpose in June 2024: https://pypi.org/project/app-store-web-scraper/ This might be an alternative to what I have now. I will try and contact the old package first.
